# Cannot post json to controller using ajax in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, coreclr

I have the following code

**Controller Action Method**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Approve(int[] ids)
    {
        await _service.Approve(ids).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return Json("Success.");
    }
```

On client side i have the following to Post data

```
var data = JSON.stringify(getIDs())

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        url: "approve",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: true,
        cache: false,
        })
        .done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // do something here
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // do something here
        })

 function getIDs() {
        var keys = [];
         keys.push(1);
         keys.push(2);
         keys.push(3);
        return keys;
    }
```

**ISSUE**
On server, in approve action method the `ids` parameter is always empty.

I have also tried sending data as

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ids:getIDs()})
```

I am using ASP.NET Core with target framework 1.1.

I have the same code in classic asp.net and it works

Comment: You are not defining `[FromBody]` Attribute in your action parameter and it wont work unless you pass them as query (very bad practice on Http requests other than GET). Or you have to send it as a form  (`multipart/form-data` mime type)

Comment: @Tseng adding [FromBody] worked. Thank You.  However i did not understand your statement `and it wont work unless you pass them as query (very bad practice on Http requests other than GET)`. I have `HttpPost` attribue defined on the action method and from client side as well i am using ajax `POST` so i am assuming data will be send in the body not as query parameter.. am i missing something? (I only missed `[FromBody]` attribute because i think in classic ASP.NET this wasn't needed)

Comment: ....and as per the jQuery documentation if `processData` is true then "data is converted to a query string, if not already a string".. so in my case i am doing `JSON.stringify()`..so data is of type string. So i data will be send in the body and not in the query string. isn't that correct?

Comment: If anyone interested..Here is why ASP.NET Core needs `FromBody` https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Read the docs please https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding. Basically when you have no `[FromBody]` attribute, it tries to read the parameter values from routes (in url) from query (url after question mark? or from form (on post requests with  `multipart/form-data`)

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you are sending a object `{ids:getIDs()}` but in your controller you expect an `array` and you don't specific from where it will come.

Change your code like this.

```
[HttpPost("approve")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Approve([FromBody]Data data)
{
    await _service.Approve(data.ids).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Json("Success.");
}

public class Data
{
    public int[] ids { get; set; }
}
```

or if you want you send the array direct in the `Ajax` POST

```
[HttpPost("approve")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Approve([FromBody]int[] ids)
{
    await _service.Approve(ids).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Json("Success.");
}
```

Ajax...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(getIDs()), //I assume getIDs returns an array of integers
    url: "/approve",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    processData: true,
    cache: false,
})
```

Comment: Thanks but as @Tseng mentioned `[FromBody]` attribute worked

Comment: Also make sure the HttpPost attribute path is relative to site root: `[HttpPost("/controller-name/approve")]`.