# The data I send to the http post method in the .net core mvc controller looks empty

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I defined a post method in .net core mvc controller. The data from the form appears blank. I couldn't get any data whatsoever. Where am I doing wrong?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696992/cannot-post-json-to-controller-using-ajax-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `[FromBody]` before `commentModel model` in the action.You pass data in body,so you need to use `[FromBody]` to get data from body.